# Why does WPE Webkit has hardware acceleration but Chromium doesn't?

Tags: chromium, xorg, web-browsers, html5

I'm working on an engineering project for a client and after various tests, the web software runs better when called from Webkit running on the framebuffer, than Chromium from the X. As it sometimes display video and CSS transforms, I suspect it has something to do with accelerated graphics.

Maybe I'm just confused, but when Chromium runs over the X Windows System, without making a lot of modifications (glshim, and others) it will disable hardware acceleration for graphics and video, but when I run WPE Webkit over the framebuffer, the browser is capable of using hardware acceleration.

What I'm trying to understand is why some browsers are capable of HWA while others are not, does it has to do with EGL, Mesa? is it the direct access to the framebuffer? is it the underlying window system? is there something I'm missing?

Thanks for your help

Comment: AFAIK Chromium has hardware 3D acceleration on a Pi.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev do I need to enable something in the configuration for it? the gpu screen is telling me is done with software. I'm using a Raspberry Pi 3 with Raspbian Buster

Comment: Try re-flashing your SD card. chrome://gpu should show "Hardware Accelerated" for almost everything there.

Comment: Alternatively, enable Fake KMS. `sudo raspi-config` --> Advanced Options --> GL Driver --> Fake KMS.